# python pandas dynamic query pass into function

Tags: pandas, function, filtering

I have the dataframe with columns of strings. I want to use a part of it in some function. A part to be used is defined by condition which passed into function.

```
def myfunc(condition):
    tmp_df = df[condition].copy()

    #doing something else wit tmp_df

    return some_result
```

My questions are:

1. How can I pass condition for string columns? For example:

   df.str_column.str.len()>10
2. How to pass an empty condition, when I need to use all dataframe?

I found solutions for numeric columns, but how to work with strings?

Comment: How *dynamic*... if you already have code that you'd like to use such as `df.str_column.str.len() > 10` - can you not just pass a dataframe that's already subsetted to `myfunc`... so you call it as `myfunc(df[df.str_column.str.len() > 10])` ?

Comment: I want to do some code with different parts of dataframe, based on different conditions. You're right! It would be easier to pass a part of dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe is necessary create boolean masks:

```
#boolean mask
cond = df.str_column.str.len()>10
#return all values
cond = [True] * len(df)

myfunc(cond)
```